# CakePHP Routes and Pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination, routes, paginator

I have created a route which looks like this

```
Router::connect('/:slug', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view'), 
                                                    array('pass' => array('slug')));
```

Until here, everything works okey, visiting the link `http://example.com/animals-and-pets`, works perfect.

On this page I have a pagination and this gives me e big problem, the links for the pages, are generating wrong, like this: http://example.com/categories/view/animals-and-pets/page:2.

The result that I want to obtain is `example.com/animals-and-pets/2`.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: this is where cake gets complicated n_n

Answer (score 0):

I once did it this way: 
[change CakePhp1.3 paginator destination url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225632/change-cakephp1-3-paginator-destination-url)

However, it could get much easier if you use `\page:2` instead of `\2`

Now in cake 2.0 I call the `$this->Paginator->options()` to set the correct url in the view before the rest of the pagination options. Something like:

```
//Set the correct url for the pagination, cake will add the "page:" and "sort:" variables to this url
$this->Paginator->options(array('url'=> array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', 'slug' => $this->params['pass'][0])));
//now display the pagination
echo $this->Paginator->counter(array('format' => __('Page {:page} of {:pages}')));
echo $this->Paginator->prev('«', array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
echo $this->Paginator->next('»', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
```

Hope this helps